# Unitizlied constant error within nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this controller:

```
class V2::OffersController > ApplicationController
```

in this file: `app/controllers/v2/offers_controller.rb`

And within that controller I am trying to reference this class:

```
module Presenters
    class Offers
```

in this file: `app/presenters/offers.rb`

I'm instantiating the class like so:

```
Presenters::Offers.new()
```

---

If I set `config.eager_load` to true everything loads fine but only on the first try, after that I keep getting this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant V2::OffersController::Presenters)
```

I'm using Rails 5.1.6.1 on Ruby 2.5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class definition for the file `app/presenters/offers.rb` should be:

```
class Offers
end
```

not

```
module Presenters
  class Offers
  end
end
```

The first level under `app` (`presenters`, in this case) is there for your organizational purposes and is not considered a module. If you want to use:

```
module Presenters
  class Offers
  end
end
```

Then the file would need to be `app/presenters/presenters/offers`.

Personally, I would do something like:

```
class OffersPresenter
end
```

which would be defined in `app/presenters/offers_presenter.rb`

Comment: Ahhhh thanks, I must've missed that bit of knowledge that the first level under app is not considered a module. Thank you!